# Converting from one base to another

Tags: c

When you have to convert a number from base 16 to base 2, what is the difference between lowercase and uppercase letters? (ex: `0Xa5B`)

I thought there was no difference, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You're right, there shouldn't be a difference.  So, depending on how you write your code, you may have to be careful that you accept and correctly process both `0xa5b` and `0XA5B`, and get the answer 2651 in either case.  If you're processing input characters yourself, one at a time, at a low (ASCII code) level, obviously `'b'` and `'B'` are two different characters, but both have to map to a digit value of 11.

Comment: One possibly-related question to think about is: When you're writing this code to convert bases, does it convert an into to an int, a string to an int, an int to a string, or a string to a string?  And the answer is that only for the inputs/outputs that are strings does it even make sense to say that they're in a "base".  Ints don't have bases; they're just integers.

Comment: If it was me, I would write a `convertFromBase` function that took a string and an `int` representing the base, and returned an `int`, and I'd write a second `convertToBase` function that took an `int`, and a second `int` representing the base, and printed or returned a string.  Then I'd take my input, base-16 string and say `int x = convertFromBase(string, 16);`, followed by `convertToBase(x, 2)` to convert to binary.

Comment: (Since 16 is a multiple of 2, there's a shortcut that could convert a string in base 16 to a string in base 2 directly, without a detour through an `int` value, and that may be what you're looking for, although what you end up with there is less general, and useless for converting, say, base 12 to base 7.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: *Since 16 is a multiple of 2*... not the correct reason: converting from base 10 to base 5 is not made easier by 10 being a *multiple* of 5, yet because 16 is a **power** of 2, the conversion can be implemented directly, one digit at a time, each hex digit producing 4 binary bits. One would still need to remove leading zeroes if required.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between upper and lower case in this context. The C language grammar and the library functions `strtol()` and similar accept both upper and lower case letters for the `0x` or `0X` prefix and the digits greater than `9` in any combination.

You can convert the string to an `unsigned long` with `strtoul()` and you will need a custom function to convert the resulting integer to its binary representation as a string.

Here is an example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Convert an unsigned long to a string of binary digits.
 * if the destination array is too short, truncate the high order bits;
 * leading zeroes are omitted (except the last one for the value 0).
 */
char *convert_to_binary(char *dest, size_t size, unsigned long value) {
    if (size > 0) {
        size_t i = size;
        dest[--i] = '\0';
        while (i > 0) {
           dest[--i] = '0' + (value & 1);
           value >>= 1;
           if (value == 0) /* remove this test if you want leading zeroes */
               break;
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            memmove(dest, dest + i, size - i);
        }
    }
    return dest;
}

int main() {
    char buf[sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT + 1];
    unsigned long value;
    const char *str = "0Xa5B";
    char *p;

    /* convert the hex string to a number */
    errno = 0;
    value = strtoul(str, &p, 16);  /* 0x prefix is ignored for base 16 */
    /* check for conversion errors */
    if (p == str) {
        fprintf(stderr, "not a number: %s\n", str);
        return 1;
    }
    if (*p != '\0') {
        fprintf(stderr, "extra characters: %s\n", str);
        return 1;
    }
    if (errno != 0) {
        /* range error */
        fprintf(stderr, "conversion error: %s: %s\n", str, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    convert_to_binary(buf, sizeof buf, value);
    printf("%s -> %s\n", str, buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Maria: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.